# Get Attribute Values from Custom Class in Talend

Tags: talend

I have new to Talend, and Everyone was going fine until I ran into basic issue. I have a function that returns more than one value, so I created a class to hold these values and my function returns a type of that class. Now, in a TMap how can call this function once, and use the same object on different columns?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use, tjava / tjavarow or tjavaflex and then collect this data and replay into tmap